# springboot APIs to use Auth0

Tags: spring-boot, auth0

We are trying to use auth0 for spring-boot application authentication.
Created Regular Web Application and Machine to Machine Applications in auth0.com and added users under User Management.
Intention is to have a login API to authenticate users and get the access-token after the successful authentication. Use access token (as bearer token) to access other APIs of the spring-boot application.

We provided proper login and callback urls under the Machine To Machine application configuration in auth0.com.

While generating bearer token, apart from **client_id**, **client_secret** we have provided **grant_type (as client_credentials)**, **audience** as https://<>/api/v2 and **scope** with (openid profile my_scope email roles).

We are getting **401** error while accessing the other APIs using bearer token generated using  **client_id, client_secret, grant_type and audience**.

Wherein, we are getting **403** error while accessing the other APIs using bearer token generated using **client_id, client_secret, grant_type, audience and scope**.

**403 error stack is as below**

```
Client is not authorized to access <<application-domain-in-auth0>>/api/v2/. You need to create a client-grant associated to this API.
```

We referred to the udemy session (https://www.udemy.com/course/build-secure-apis-with-auth0-and-postman/learn/lecture/12716335#overview)

Any inputs on the overall approach and where we are going wrong.

Thanks

Venkata Madhu

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it can help, but found this more relevant to the problem statement.

https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-generate-a-management-api-token-automatically/6376

There are a few things you need to do/check:

Create a non-interactive client in Auth0, which will be used to represent your service.
Authorize the non-interactive client to call the Auth0 Management API:
Dashboard > APIs > Auth0 Management API > Non Interactive Clients > Authorize your client
Ensure that the parameters used in the call to /oauth/token are for your non interactive client:
{
grant_type: 'client_credentials',
client_id: 'NON-INTERACTIVE-CLIENT-ID',
client_secret: 'NON-INTERACTIVE-CLIENT-SECRET',
audience: 'https://yourdomain.auth0.com/api/v2/"    }
Make sure the access token you receive is passed in the Authorization header for every request made to the Management API. Authorization: Bearer <access_token>